# How to copy a file after saving it in eclipse (with ant)?

Tags: eclipse, ant

I need to copy a file after saving it to another directory - how can I achieve this? My first attempt is to use an ant builder that always (after a clean, after a build ...) copies all files of my project to the target directory. This works fine but if you have 1000 and more of files in your project, it gets to slow. So I just want to automatically copy the file that I've just edited/created to a specific directory.

Answer (score 2):

http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/index.html

This is a filesync plugin for eclipse. Pretty fast and incremental. I always use it for such cases. You define mapping, and it is a native (java) builder, that is assigned to your project. Works with path variables as well, if you need to achieve workstation independent settings.

ps:
What do you use it for? Since I recently used it, but I realized, this is usually evil thing :) Do you tell me the use-case for this?

Comment: Thanks! We will give it a try or use ant's sync task.

Comment: That is not working in Eclipse 4.7.x.
Maybe it is because I'm using PHP mode instead of JAVA.